# 1-loop Feynman diagrams of $g \to gg$ in pure QCD

Tags: quantum-field-theory, computational-physics, feynman-diagrams, quantum-chromodynamics, software

I'm very new to QFT, and I'm drawing one-loop Feynman diagrams of the process $g \to gg$ in pure QCD. I use MadGraph to generate all the diagrams by

```
> generate g > g g [virt=QCD]
> display diagrams
```

and it gives me

[image]

(I deleted some pictures since I'm only interested in pure gluons diagrams now). Moreover, the FeynCalc gives the same answer. You can find it in their example gallery https://feyncalc.github.io/FeynCalcExamplesMD/QCD/OneLoop/Gl-GlGl

So, my question is why kinds of the following 1-loop diagram do not show up in this process?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that the software only gives 1PI (One-Particle Irreducible) diagrams. The diagram you want is not 1PI, and is different from the tree diagram only by a gluon self-energy term.

Try sections 8,9 [here](https://www.imperial.ac.uk/media/imperial-college/research-centres-and-groups/theoretical-physics/msc/current/qft/handouts/qftdiagramtypes.pdf).

Comment: Oh, the last diagram is the same as the tree diagram after amputation. I am careless. Really thank you!